# What is the alternative method for the "self.isTouchEnabled " in Cocos2d 2.0?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

When I use the

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES
```

in `Cocos2d v2.0` for the layer could be touched,the Xcode  give me a tip:

```
setIsTouchEnabled: is deprecated
```

Now, I just want to know alternative method for isTouchEnabled.

Comment: Which version/branch of cocos2d are you using?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here is new code:

```
    self.touchEnabled = YES; //In Cocos2d 2.0

    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES; //In Cocos2d 3.0
```

Just wondering  why **genius people(Cocos2d team)** doing this kind of **silly change**!

But this one is the right call to setup touch in Cocos2d 2.x and above !!!

Comment: this is one of the reasons I am migrating all my projects from Cocos2D to SpriteKit. Every new version of Cocos2D is a nightmare of problems.

Comment: The idea behind this change is to make the naming consistent with UIKit. I believe this is a good idea in the long run even though it requires some migration from 2.x to 3.x.

Answer (score 7):

It seems the `setIsTouchEnabled` is located in "CCDeprecated.h" now.

The following method is in the current "CCLayer.h":

```
[self setTouchEnabled:YES]
```