# cocos2d self.touchEnabled = YES not found

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
-(id)init
{
  if ((self = [super init]))
  {

    [self setupTitle];
    self.touchEnabeled = YES;

  }
return self;
}

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

[[CCDirector sharedDirector]
replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[GameScene node]]];
CCSprite *start = (CCSprite *)
[self getChildByTag:1]; [start stopAllActions];
start.visible = NO;

 }
```

Cant Get self.touchEnabled = YES; working it gives an error ;

touchEnabled Not found on object type of 'TitleLayer'

Comment: You have a typo in your code: self.touchEnab**e**led

Comment: which version of cocos2d you are using ?

Comment: using v2 should I upgrade to v3 for v2 tutorial ? @NatureFriend

Comment: self.touchEnabeled available in Cocos2d 2.0 only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304652/what-is-the-alternative-method-for-the-self-istouchenabled-in-cocos2d-2-0/14304895#14304895

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In older versions, the code is:

```
self.touchEnabled = YES;
```

Try just copying this and putting it in.

Answer (score 0):

This property is called `userInteractionEnabled` since cocos2d v3.0.

If you're using older version of cocos2d try to fix the typo in your code. The right name for property is `touchEnabled`.